# How do you change (email, password) to (username,password) with ASP.net Identity

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-5, entity-framework-6, asp.net-identity

I tough this would have been trivial and provided in the MVC template, but actually creating ASP.NET project > MVC 5/EF6 with Individual Account is giving me an email, password credentials combination. Strange considering the [Getting Started](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/introduction-to-aspnet-identity) of Identity shows username, password combination.

[image]

While many seems to want to do the other way around I actually want to convert that default (email, password) behavior to a more basic (username, password). But that seems to require manual modification to the controller, startup, layout and model. Actually what exactly do I have to change to achieve this?

Note that my setup is the basic Visual Studio 2013 Community Edition with nothing more.

Comment: Check this question I have answered it in here. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28138278/register-with-username-using-identity-2-1/28148507#28148507

Answer (score 0):

A hint, This is to change from username to email. In your account controller

```
public AccountController(UserManager<User> userManager)
{
    UserManager = userManager;

    //Login using Email instead of Username, disable UserName validation
    var userValidator = UserManager.UserValidator as UserValidator<User>;
    if (userValidator != null) userValidator.AllowOnlyAlphanumericUserNames = false;
}
```

And I think you need to change your view model too